# SQL Server XML node value

Tags: sql-server, xml

From within SQL Server, I want to get the nth (2nd) tag value within a XML object record

```
declare @xml xml = 
'<animals>
    <dog>
        <petname>fred</petname>
    </dog>
    <cat>
        <petname>bill</petname>
    </cat>
</animals>'

select 
    n.value('petname[1]','varchar(10)') as name,
    n.value('../(*).name()[1]','varchar(10)') as animalType  -- don't know how to get this???
from 
    @xml.nodes('animals/*') as a(n)
```

The results I want:

```
name   animalType
-----------------
fred   dog
bill   cat
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the local-name?

```
declare @xml xml = 
'<animals>
    <dog>
        <petname>fred</petname>
    </dog>
    <cat>
        <petname>bill</petname>
    </cat>
</animals>'

select 
n.value('petname[1]','varchar(10)') as name,
n.value('local-name(.)','varchar(10)') as animalType
from @xml.nodes('animals/*') as a(n)
```